# Multitask learning in GPFlow with missing inputs?

Tags: gpflow

Is it possible to do multitask learning with GPFlow where some inputs are missing? Specifically, I am trying to fit spatial data from several related individuals, but the data are not at identical input locations for all individuals. I know I ought to be doing hierarchical GPs here, but they tend not to scale well. I was hoping that multitask learning might be used instead, though the use case does not map exactly onto the typical application of this method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently not a model in GPflow that does this. However, GPflow does provide tools to easily implement this. Two suggestions:

- Use a multioutput kernel, and for missing datapoints you set your observation variance to infinity.
- Define a multioutput kernel, and specify a custom `Kuf` for which the requested outputs are passed together with the corresponding input.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible to do multitask learning with GPFlow where some inputs are missing?

Absolutely, yes.

The way GPflow does this is by stacking the output index onto the input. For example, suppose you have two outputs (0, 1) observed at locations [0.1, 0.2, 0.3] and [0.3, 0.4, 0.5], you'y construct the "input matrix"

```
[0.1 0]
[0.2 0]
[0.3 0]
[0.3 1]
[0.4 1]
[0.5 1]
```

Then, specify how the kernel acts on this matrix using "active_dims". The simplest kernel that could act on this model would be:

k = gpflow.kernels.Matern32(1, active_dims=[0]) * gpflow.kernels.Coregion(1, 2, 2, active_dims=[1])

Which is the intrinsic coregionalization model (see Alvarez et al, [1]). You can gfind a more detailed demo in the GPflow documentation, [here](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/GPflow/GPflow/blob/develop/doc/source/notebooks/advanced/coregionalisation.ipynb).

Note that you probably want a more powerful model that intrinsic coregionalization: the Linear Model of Coregionalization is more powerful and still easy to implement.

[1] http://eprints.whiterose.ac.uk/114503/1/1106.6251v2.pdf

Comment: A useful notebook that already implements the LMC is https://github.com/silburt/gp_nn/blob/master/Coregion-py3.ipynb

Just make sure to change the way Switched Likelihood is created to something like

gpflow.likelihoods.SwitchedLikelihood([gpflow.likelihoods.StudentT() for i in range(output_dim)])